# How to get the position of a key within an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

Ok, so I need to grab the position of 'blah' within this array (position will not always be the same).  For example:

```
$array = (
    'a' => $some_content,
    'b' => $more_content,
    'c' => array($content),
    'blah' => array($stuff),
    'd' => $info,
    'e' => $more_info,
);
```

So, I would like to be able to return the number of where the 'blah' key is located at within the array.  In this scenario, it should return 3.  How can I do this quickly?  And without affecting the $array array at all.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
$i = array_search('blah', array_keys($array));
```

Answer (score 10):

If you know the key exists:

PHP 5.4 ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/upUZdA)):

```
echo array_flip(array_keys($array))['blah'];
```

PHP 5.3:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($array));
echo $keys['blah'];
```

If you don't know the key exists, you can check with `isset`:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($array));
echo isset($keys['blah']) ? $keys['blah'] : 'not found' ;
```

This is merely like `array_search` but makes use of the map that exists already inside any array. I can't say if it's really better than `array_search`, this might depend on the scenario, so just another alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I know for a fact that the key will always exist!  In that case, would this be faster than using `array_search`?

Comment: Let me answer this way: As long as `array_flip` is faster than `array_search`, it is :). The key lookup itself is faster than `array_search`.

Comment: I like the idea, but array_search is actually faster according to my tests (at least in PHP 5.3).

Comment: Depends if you need many lookups in the same array... If you search for - say - all keys, *array_search* is O(n²), with *array_flip* that would be O(n). If you need a couple of lookups go for *search*. (for both solutions you would of course save the intermediate array in another variable in case you need multiple lookups, sake of perf)

Answer (score 1):

`$keys=array_keys($array);` will give you an array containing the keys of `$array`

So, `array_search('blah', $keys);` will give you the index of `blah` in `$keys` and therefore, `$array`

Answer (score -3):

User `array_search` ([doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)). Namely, `$index = array_search('blah', $array)

Comment: No ! Like the doc says: Searches the array for a given **value**, not a **key** as the user asked.